# How do Christians / churches who self-identify as "post-Protestant" distinguish themselves from non-denominational or evangelical?

Tags: protestantism, evangelicalism, fundamentalism, non-denominational

I came across a blog author [Matthew Bryan](https://conciliarpost.com/author/matthew-bryan/) who self-identify as a "post-Protestant", a term that I encountered for the first time.  When I Googled what "post-Protestant" means, I came across [this entry](https://religion.wikia.org/wiki/Post-Protestant) from *religion.wikia.org*:

> Post-Protestantism is the movement in 20th century and 21st Christianity to even further remove Christian faith from the influence and traditions of the Roman Catholic church and "her sister churches" (traditional, mainline, liturgical Protestant denominations dating back mostly to the 1600s and 1700s).
>
> Many of these "post-Protestant" churches refer to themselves simply as "Christian", or nondenominational, but also commonly use the terms "Church of", followed by such words as "God", "Christ", "Jesus", "The Bible", etc. The trend was the natural outgrowth of the evangelical and fundamentalist movements of the earlier 20th century (1900s), and partly includes, but is not limited to, Restorationists and the Community Church movement, who refer to themselves as being post-Protestant and postdenominational.
>
> These leaders of these often promote points of view which are anti-intellectual, or at least ahistorical, to the point that they totally deny or are even oblivious to the history of Christian denominations, and the meaning of the word Protestant (which essentially, is any Christian who is not a Roman Catholic, Eastern Catholic, or Eastern Orthodox Christian). This often adds to the confusion and ignorance of people who mistakenly believe that only churches with the words "Christian", "Christ", or "Jesus" in the name are Christian, and that Baptists, Methodists, Lutherans, Catholics, etc. are something else.

I'm looking for a good article from either a religious studies scholar or a Christian / church that self-identify as "post-Protestant" that can do at least a few of the following:

- explain why they don't simply use the term "non-denominational" or "evangelical"
- describe specific hermeneutical principles that they use to interpret Bible, which distinguish them from evangelicals
- describe their understanding of *sola scriptura* since they seem to reject mainstream Protestant (and even some evangelical!) use of the early church councils to narrow down certain interpretation of the Bible (for example, to reject non-Trinitarian interpretation)
- describe several theological positions that unite them as a group (for example, their view of the Lord's supper, baptism, and gifts of the Holy Spirit)
- speak for others who identify as "post-Protestant"

Comment: This 2019 article [Dreaming of a Post-Protestant Movement](https://medium.com/solus-jesus/dreaming-of-a-post-protestant-movement-8db9e55d2f0a) promoting her book [Solus Jesus: A Theology of Resistance](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40783859-solus-jesus) may provide a clue.

Comment: As far as I am able to grasp his thoughts, the writer seems to lament the fact that LGBTQ issues are second-tire to most churches, including the ones affirming them, thus serving only to split, and therefore weaken the community (*divide and conquer*). He seems to propose the creation of a new denomination, whose primary aim is integration or acceptance, and for which the issues currently regarded as more important are relegated to a secondary status. More or less like Anglicanism, but with the unity being predicated upon inclusivity or orientation, rather than nationality.

Comment: @Lucian Personally, I'm deeply skeptical that a post-Protestant position like that can have a center that brings people together like the historic Anglican, Reformed, or Arminian (which has survived for several centuries), hence my question.

Comment: Your skepticism seems misplaced; people in the middle ages were keenly interested in theological trivia; modern ones usually are not (or only to the extent to which they also touch upon moral issues, as opposed to being purely theological).

Comment: Interesting question, to which I have no answer.  However, there may be a clue in this article: https://www.gotquestions.org/emerging-church-emergent.html